# Should "Good Morning" always be used as the first greeting of the day?

Tags: time, greetings

Is it true that regardless of the time of the day, the first wish to a person must be **Good morning**? Even if I meet him in the afternoon?

Comment: Could you point to a source that states this rule? I have never heard it, and it is not correct.

Comment: I am also very curious as to where you got this idea. Pray tell!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No it is not.

- *Good morning* - any time in the morning after waking up
- *Good afternoon* - between noon and evening
- *Good evening* - in the evening
- *Good day* - any time, but it feels old-fashioned

*Good night* never means "hello", always "goodbye".

There are times of day when there is no really appropriate "Good ..." -- for example, *Good morning* is not appropriate if you join your friends in a nightclub at 12:30 am, but neither is *Good evening*.

Comment: I have heard “good day” used as a farewell— but when I hear it at all it is usually in a film.

Comment: They may all be used as a farewell, but all will sound old fashioned for that, apart from "Good night".

Comment: 'G'day' is Australian.

Comment: @Barrie: I thought the correct phrase was, "G'day mate".

Comment: @Jay: Certainly, but I suspect the appellation is optional.

Answer (score 1):

Slim is entirely correct.

One occasional exception to those rules is that "Good morning" is often used ironically.

For example, if it's 4pm and I meet a coworker who looks tired, I might say "Good morning" in a joking tone, implying that he seems to have just woken up.

Or if a friend accompanied me to a late-night movie and fell asleep halfway through it, when I woke her up after the movie I might say "Good morning" as a friendly way of ribbing her for falling asleep.

Comment: Or, indeed, if you arrive at the office at 9:10 when the day strictly starts at 9, a colleague might say "good afternoon" as a joke.

Comment: Touché, good sir.